# Using sprites as hover backgrounds on images

Tags: html, css

I am noticing a pretty hefty amount of loading time on the first visit to a page I created. My goal was to make a "meet us" page for my wife's company where when the user hovers over a photo, a different photo + text fade in appears. I finally figured this out and I love the the effect. The columns are responsive and I have no issues other than the fact that when I first visit the page, each time I hover over an image it's taking around 1 full second to load.

I read an article about sprites, which apparently help loading times. The problem is, the article formats html/css in a specific way, much different than the way I formatted my columns. I am not eager to completely re-work my code so I was wondering if someone could explain to me how to implement sprites with the code I currently have.

Also, I am sure my code is super messy and parts of it are redundant. I'm also pretty sure I could condense all of the redundant parts I'm just not 100% on how.

Here is the code:

```css
  .meetuscontainer {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}

.meetusimg1 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/sLL_Proofs-141chelseaport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg2 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/sLL_Proofs-256heatherport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg3 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/SMLL_Proofs-312momport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg4 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/SMLL_Proofs-287magport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg5 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/LL_Proofs-120annieports.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg6 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/LL_Proofs-055kimports.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg7 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/sLL_Proofs-257connorport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimg8 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/LL_Proofs-088danielleports.jpg?6924964667493824007");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.meetusimgtext {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 29px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 350px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.meetusimgtext2 {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 350px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  color: #a1ffd2;
  font-family: "Pacifico", sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


/* Gallery */

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.meetusimg1:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/sLL_Proofs-141chelseaport2.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg2:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/sLL_Proofs-268heatherport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg3:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/LL_Proofs-014momports.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg4:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/SLL_Proofs-403magport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg5:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/sLL_Proofs-111annieport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg6:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/LL_Proofs-048kimports.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg7:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/amLL_Proofs-271connorport.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg8:hover {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/SLL_Proofs-500daniellepor2t.jpg?6924964667493824007");
}

.meetusimg1:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg1:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg2:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg2:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg3:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg3:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg4:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg4:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg5:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg5:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg6:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg6:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg7:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg7:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg8:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg8:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg9:hover .meetusimgtext {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.meetusimg9:hover .meetusimgtext2 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .meetusimg1,
  .meetusimg2,
  .meetusimg3,
  .meetusimg4,
  .meetusimg5,
  .meetusimg6,
  .meetusimg7,
  .meetusimg8,
  .meetusimg9,
  .meetusimgtext,
  .meetusimgtext2 {
    max-width: 280px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="meetuscontainer">
  <div class="gallery">
    <figure class="meetusimg1">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">CHELSEA EARLY</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Founder + Designer</div>
    </figure>
    <figure class="meetusimg2">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">HEATHER WALKER</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Founder + Designer</div>
    </figure>
    <figure class="meetusimg3">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">KAREN SAARI</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Founder + Administrator</div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="meetuscontainer">
  <div class="gallery">
    <figure class="meetusimg4">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">MAGGIE HABROS</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Cutter</div>
    </figure>
    <figure class="meetusimg5">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">ANNIE MIHULKA</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Serger</div>
    </figure>
    <figure class="meetusimg6">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">KIM THEISEN</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Cutter</div>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="meetuscontainer">
  <div class="gallery">
    <figure class="meetusimg7">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">CONNOR JONES</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Top Stitcher</div>
    </figure>
    <figure class="meetusimg8">
      <div class="meetusimgtext">DANIELLE PFANNENSTIEL</div>
      <div class="meetusimgtext2">Elastics</div>
    </figure>
    <!--<figure class="meetusimg9">
<div class="meetusimgtext">STEPHANIE TRAWICK</div>
<div class="meetusimgtext2">Cutter</div>
</figure>-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The response is good when I hover over the images. Maybe it's the hosting company you have which has poor response. Anyway, if you want to try a sprite, I'd be quite happy to create one for you. If it works as expected, you can do the other ones yourself.

Comment: Yeah, that's a crazy amount of repetition in your CSS. A "class", by strict definition, is a set of like things. Add one to each of your `.meetusimg` elements that contains the rules that you're repeating.  You can replace the list in your media query with it, too.

Comment: OOoooooooh I get it now. It makes a ton of sense just seeing it with the image. That's super simple, I'll definitely do that :)

Comment: Hmmm I'll have to experiment on how to condense the code. I definitely know that it's incredibly messy and repetitive. I am just a little new yet to know exactly how to condense. I'll figure it out.

You're saying just add an additional div class that is the parent of the "meetusimg#" that contains the margin, width, height, background elements, and transitions? and then I would leave each individual class for each background sprite transition?

Comment: Just copy the snippet and change the URL

Comment: Few more tips: You're not floating anything, no need for the _clearfix_. Not sure I would use `<figure>` with background images. I would wrap _name_ and _title_ in a single element (this will simplify placement as both move together). Then use something more semantic like `<h2>` and `<h3>`. No need to set a width equal to a parent/ancestor element like you did with _name_ and _title_ when using block level elements like a `<div>`. Use more descriptive class names: `.staff`, `.staff-title` and `.staff-name`. Don't use all caps in source, use `text-transform: uppercase;` for that.

Comment: I revised the code:

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Including transition

```css
.meetusimg1 {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/54AbA.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  transition:background-position 1s ease;
}

.meetusimg1:hover {
  background-position: -350px 0;
}
```

```html
<figure class="meetusimg1">
  <div class="meetusimgtext">CHELSEA EARLY</div>
  <div class="meetusimgtext2">Founder + Designer</div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all the answers. I went ahead and revised my code based off of everything you said. I think it looks a TON better. Only issue I'm having is that between h2 and P there is a strange amount of padding that I didn't tell the css to put there. I changed the padding and margin to 0px on the staff-text p and that seemed to help

```css
/* Container */
.staff-container { 
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  clear: both; 
}

/* Gallery */
.staff-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* All Staff Image Styling */
.staff-img {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 525px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
}

/* All Staff Text Styling */
.staff-text {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.staff-text h2{
  padding-top: 275px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.staff-text p{
  font-family: "Pacifico", sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.staff-img:hover .staff-text {
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.6s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Img Hover */
.staff-img:hover {
 background-position: -350px 0;
}

.chelsea {
 background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2185/4785/files/1-ChelseaSprite_f89345e7-ea1e-4186-af48-d8a957b0d8b5.jpg?5470095217541866382"); 
}
```

```html
<div class="staff-container">
  <div class="staff-gallery">
   <div class="staff-img chelsea">
    <div class="staff-text">
      <h2>Chelsea Early</h2>
      <p>Founder + Designer</p>
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="staff-img chelsea">
    <div class="staff-text">
      <h2>Chelsea Early</h2>
      <p>Founder + Designer</p>
    </div>
   </div>
     <div class="staff-img chelsea">
    <div class="staff-text">
      <h2>Chelsea Early</h2>
      <p>Founder + Designer</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Browsers have default styles they apply to various elements. Virtually every site will use a [**CSS reset**](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or a CSS framework of some type to normalize those styles across browsers. Also, for `.staff-text` you don't need `flex-wrap`, `justify-content` or `width`. `.staff-text` is a block element so it will take up the width of the parent element, which already has `width: 350px;`, therefore redundant. The flexbox properties are not need because `.staff-text` is not a flexbox element. Big improvements overall with the markup and naming conventions.